# How to call a JavaScript function only once in the browser for given site, even browser refresh should not call the function again

Tags: javascript

Looking for JavaScript code which will be called on load of the site for first time of login and any further refreshes should not call the function. Tried using the global variable but of not much help.

Tried using the golbal variables in Java script but they are getting refreshed on browser refresh.

Comment: You need to set a cookie or put something in localStorage/sessionStorage then test if this is true on reload

Comment: Or if it's an SPA this can be done once on the initial page load. You probably have to tell us more about your application

Comment: Thanks @lharby let me try with localStorage